# Incluindo colunas em um dataframe no R utilizando uma regra

Tags: r, dplyr

Esse é meu dataframe:

```
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=10))
colnames(df)<-c("one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten")
```

Esse é o indice que usarei como exemplo:

```
index<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

Minha ideia é criar colunas e preenchendo os valores -2, -1, 0, 1 ou 2 nessas colunas criadas de acordo com uma regra.

Seria assim: Vou criar uma coluna AO LADO da coluna "One" e vou chama-la de "One_new":

Na hora de preencher essa coluna com valores seguirei a seguinte regra:

Se o valor na coluna "One" for menor que 1 (index[1]) e maior que -1(-index[1]) recebe o valor 0.

Se o valor na coluna "One" for maior que 1 (index[1]) e menor que 2*(index[1]) recebe o valor 1.

Se o valor na coluna "One" for maior que 2*(index[1]) recebe o valor 2.

Se o valor na coluna "One" for menor que -1*(index[1]) e maior que -2*(index[1]) recebe o valor -1.

Se o valor na coluna "One" for menor que -2*(index[1]) recebe o valor -2.

Vou percorrer essa regra para todas as colunas. O que muda é o valor referencia que para a segunda coluna sera index[2], para a terceira index[3],...,até a para coluna 10 index[10]

Preciso que essas colunas criadas fiquem ao lado das colunas. Ou seja, a coluna One_new deve ficar ao lado da coluna One, a coluna Two_new ao lado da coluna Two e por ai vai.

Consigo fazer isso com o pacote dplyr?

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma, usando `purrr` e `dplyr`.

```
res <- map2_dfc(df, index, function(x, index) {
  case_when(
    x < -2*index ~ -2,
    x < -1*index ~ -1,
    x <  1*index  ~  0,
    x <  2*index  ~  1,
    TRUE         ~  2
    )
}) %>%
  set_names(paste0(names(.), "_new")) %>%
  bind_cols(df)
```

A função `map2` do `purrr` é usada para aplicar a função para cada coluna do data.frame e index.

Note que o resultado final não coloca as colunas lado a lado. Isso poderia ser feito usando posteriormente a função `select`.

Para selecionar na ordem que você quer, é possível fazer assim:

```
res %>%
  select(flatten_chr(map(colnames(df), ~c(.x , paste0(.x , "_new")))))
```

Comment: Bom Daniel funcionou perfeitamente. Para usar o comando select eu devo fazer com que  se faça o "match" dos nomes das colunas né? A cada "match" eu coloco as duas colunas juntas e por vai ne?

Comment: Fiz um exemplo de como pode ser feito.. Não sei se seria a melhor forma..

Comment: sempre muito solicito. Muito obrigada novamente.